# NEO4JRESTCLIENT - Deleting all nodes/ rels query issue?

Tags: python, neo4j

All, starting with neo4j and it's restclient and trying to send a cypher query to delete all nodes:

```
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
query1 = """START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[r?]-()
WHERE ID(n) <> 0
DELETE n,r"""
gdb.query(q=query1)

query2 = """start r=node(*) return count(r)"""
print gdb.query(q=query2)[0]
```

Using the second query to count nodes indicates that the first query didn't run (properly at least). Note that query1 works fine in the neo4j data browser.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query statement only builds a `QuerySequence` object. Unless you require the result, e.g. by trying to access the result, or by calling `get_response`, nothing is executed.

You can see that the nodes are actually deleted:

```
query1 = """START n=node(*)
         MATCH n-[r?]-()
         WHERE ID(n) <> 0
         DELETE n,r
         RETURN COUNT(n)"""

print gdb.query(query1).get_response()
# something like {u'columns': [u'COUNT(n)'], u'data': [[3]]}
```

Comment: that makes sense; what i'm wondering is why query2 (count nodes) works without the need to issue a .get_response()? Is it because the return is embedded in the Cypher query to begin with?

Comment: no, but you're requiring the response implicitly when you're printing its first element

Comment: As of `neo4jrestclient` 2.0.0, a new argument, `lazy`, is added in order to force the execution of the query when needed: `print gdb.query(query1, lazy=False)`